# Using a variable inside a member of an object

Tags: c#

I am pulling several elements of data out of an object in C#. They are all in the same 'place' within the object, as in:

```
objectContainer.TableData.Street.ToString());
objectContainer.TableData.City.ToString());
objectContainer.TableData.State.ToString());
objectContainer.TableData.ZipCode.ToString());
```

I would LIKE to use a foreach loop to pull them all and be able to add more by adding to the array.

```
string[] addressFields = new string[] { "Street", "City", "State", "ZipCode" };
foreach(string add in addressFields) 
{
  objectContainer.TableData.{add}.ToString());
}
```

Can this be done, and if so, what is the correct procedure?

Comment: what is TableData ?? What type is it?

Comment: Are you trying to add items to your TableData, or you want to get items from TableData? Your intent is not clear

Comment: I am trying to Get and yes, the GetType().GetProperty() is what I was looking for and couldn't find. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use reflection to achieve this:

```
var type = objectContainer.TableData.GetType();

foreach(var addressFieldName in addressFieldNames)
{
    var property = type.GetProperty(addressFieldName);
    if(property == null)
        continue;
    var value = property.GetValue(objectContainer.TableData, null);
    var stringValue = string.Empty;
    if(value != null)
        stringValue = value.ToString();
}
```

Please note: This code is pretty defensive:

- It will not crash if no property with the specified name exists.
- It will not crash if the value of the property is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to do this.

```
string[] addressFields = new string[] { "Street", "City", "State", "ZipCode" };
foreach(string add in addressFields) 
{
  var myVal = objectContainer.TableData.GetType().GetProperty(add).GetValue(objectContainer.TableData).ToString();
}
```

Note that this doesn't allow for array values that don't have a corresponding property on objectContainer.TableData.